# why newly created vm using pxe boot is not listing in the maas

Tags: networking, maas, pxe

I am using MAAS. MAASRC and MAASCC in different nodes. And I have created new VM using PXE boot. But the newly created VM is not listing in the maas. What should be the issue with this.

When I try to ping google.com from new VM I am getting timeout error.

```
backdoor@ubuntu:/var/log$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.199.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
```

Following is the details of new VM

```
 backdoor@ubuntu:/var/log$ ifconfig
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:2f:ac:42  
          inet addr:10.20.0.164  Bcast:10.20.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe2f:ac42/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:201658192 (201.6 MB)  TX bytes:3030291 (3.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

Following is the logs

- http://pastebin.com/3JpTa6nq
- http://pastebin.com/Y4wCg58X

Please advice me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details on the network setup of the CC and the node itself, i.e. what interfaces are on each and what VLANs and subnets they are connected to?

Answer (score 0):

On the maas region controller, it needs to have a 10.20.x.x IP (the
10.20.x.x IP assigned on the maas) and be telling its VMs its helping boot
to reach it there. This IP configured in
/etc/maas/region*.conf. It likely is set to 192.168.122.159 right now.
Hopefully there is a 10.20.x.x IP on the maasrc instance and this setting
needs to be updated.

By setting the ip  10.20.x.x in /etc/maas/regiond.conf solve the issue.

Thank you Alan.